# Binding of variable not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I created a custom directive and I want to perform a simple variable binding. When I set the data directly everything is displayed properly but when I use my query no data is set yet my console output shows me that the variable got assigned.

This is my directive:

```
function tutorialCourse(){
return{
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'app/tutorial/tutorialCourse.html',
    controller: 'TutorialCourseController',
    controllerAs: 'tutorial'
};
};
```

and this  is my controller:

```
    TutorialCourseController.$inject = ['$q', 'Course'];

function TutorialCourseController($q, Course){

    this.course = {};

    loadTutorial();

    function loadTutorial(){
       Course.query().$promise.then(function(courses){
           this.course = _.first(courses);
           console.log(this.course)

       });
   };

}
```

my html is really simple:

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">{{tutorial.course.title}} </h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

I already tried to return the values in laodTutorial and use the function call to assign it directly to the course variable but that didn't work. But if I do this

```
this.course = {id: 11, title: "Tutorial"}
```

everything works fine. Any Idea what I am not understanding or doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `this.course` using inside the query callback function is not the `this`(context) outside the function. Because each javascript function has their own context when they get instantiate/executed.

You could solve this problem by storing controller context in `var self = this;`, and use `self` while pointing to `TutorialCourseController` context. By lexical scoping Javascript will resolve value of `self` variable.

```
TutorialCourseController.$inject = ['$q', 'Course'];

function TutorialCourseController($q, Course){
    var self = this;
    self.course = {};

    loadTutorial();

    function loadTutorial(){
       Course.query().$promise.then(function(courses){
           self.course = _.first(courses);
           console.log(this.course);
       });
   };
}
```

Reference to [**John Papa styleguide**](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#style-y033)

Comment: Nice, but why didn't returning the result work? Like 

this.course = loadTutorial();

and in loadTutorial:
return _.first(courses)

Comment: @x3lq that would work only if you return a promise from `loadTutorial` function. And don't forget to resolve it when `query` function resolved. But then it would be an Promise object, since `ngResourece` unwrap response object for you.